# Using jquery to determine screen width

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, width

Having trouble getting this script to run properly on an iphone 6. Keeps coming up as "not mobile". What am I missing?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(window).width < 700){
        alert("mobile");
    }
    else {
        alert("not mobile");
    }
});
```

EDIT: apologies, the code I typed here had a typo, but was not the cause for my issue. I had inaccurate info on iphone resolution. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The iPhone 6 display has a resolution of 1334x750. When emulating iPhone6 in chrome dev tools the width is reported as `980` (I don't know if this is accurate).

You might be interested in this: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Also, as others have noted, replace `$(window).width` with `$(window).width()`

Comment: Whats the difference between viewport size and resolution?

http://viewportsizes.com/?filter=iphone%206

Comment: The site does not show any infos about device width/height. Go to whatismyscreenresolution.net instead.

Comment: As this is old, I'm not sure you have figured it out the problem with mobile screens. But this solved the issue for me. Just add this in your <head> tag. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Answer (score 18):

Well, ignoring [what ekuusela said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29883354/1863564) about screen resolution, you seem to have forgotten your parentheses after `width`, which is a method, not a field. To fix this, just add `()` after it:

```
if ($(window).width() < 700)
```

See [the documentation for `width()`](https://api.jquery.com/width/) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

iPhone6 screen is 1334x750 pixels.
If you only use the width to detect mobile user, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery) instead.

Answer (score 2):

JQuery uses `$(window).width()`. It's a function, not a property.

Comment: Gosh*darnit* you were 15 seconds faster than me.

Comment: To be fair, I typed significantly less than you. :p

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bootstrap add an element to the screen that only displays at a certain break point (bootstrap 4):

```
<div id="IsMobile" class="d-block d-lg-none"></div>
```

Then if it's visible:

```
if ($("#IsMobile").is(":visible")) {
     //Do Something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want `.width()`, not just `.width`. Also, log it and make sure it's what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

This thread gets deep into the options both in Javascript and JQuery

[Get the size of the screen, current web page and browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window)

Answer (score 0):

```
function isMobileDevice() {
    return (typeof window.orientation !== "undefined") || 
        (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('IEMobile') !== -1);
}
```

This is a legacy way of checking.  You should probably use something like this:

```
const isMobile = ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement && /mobi/i.test(navigator.userAgent));
```